# Need suggestions , making function to "put site offline" 

Tags: web, offline-mode

I am upto making a function for mine website's administrator to put it offline.
But site must be some way accessible for administrators or mods.

What way i should do it  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somewhere in the includes:

```
if($mainstance == 1){
    if(strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'/admin/') === false) die("Site's down");
}
```

This would make everything but the /admin/ directory inaccessible.